# Example of using SSH to access private data in builds provided in Docker documentation not working on my machines

Tags: docker, ssh, openssh

I've followed the instructions mentioned in the [Docker documentation to use SSH to access private data in builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).

I've added my SSH private key into the SSH authentication agent using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Then I just created the same Dockerfile provided in the documentation (except the git repo to clone which I replaced by another one):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone private repository
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git myproject
```

If I try to build the image with the following command:

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

I get this error:

```
------
 > [stage-0 3/4] RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts]: exit code: 1
```

The instruction causing the build failure is actually `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` which returns exit code 1.

I've tried it on 3 local machines: Windows, Ubuntu and Mac, and I always get the same error.
On all of these machines I'm able to use my SSH key to clone git repositories, but also on all of them the instruction `ssh-keyscan github.com` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the issue like here: https://adamo.wordpress.com/2021/12/17/run-mounttypessh-is-not-always-easy/

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh env
RUN --mount=type=ssh ls -l ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:repo/proj.git
```